# How to render messages along with a login block programmatically

Tags: 7, theming

I rendered `Drupal Login Block` and `Frogot Password Page` in a region so I can trigger it in a bootstrap modal upon user click on login link, here's the code for those who might actually need it:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="loginpass-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="messages-dude">
          <?php print $messages; ?>
        </div>
          <div class="user-login-modal">
            <?php
              $login = drupal_get_form("user_login_block");
              $form = drupal_render($login);
              echo $form;
            ?>
          </div>

          <div class="user-pass-modal">
            <?php
            // include user form
            module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
            $passform = drupal_get_form('user_pass');
            $passformrender = drupal_render($passform);
            echo $passformrender;
            ?>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn user-modal-close">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-left nobrainer">Forgot password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when a user enters wrong credentials and system wants to render an error message, it renders the error on page and not in the modal, even though I tried printing `$messages` as you can see in the code, it still doesn't show the error in the modal, I was wondering if there is a way to show the error in the modal,

Thanks.